# Octave - Linear Solving for PageRank

Tags: octave, linear-algebra, linear-programming, pagerank

I would like to compare the result of Octave linear solving vs the Power method iteration I have done in Python. The both are in norm L1.

Since I am new in Octave, I would like to use eig to do the computation for the first three iterations in order to get a idea about the differences.

(based on the formula : Xt * G = Xt  where G is the google matrix, Xt the Left Eigenvector)

Here is my current code:

```
# Constants
alpha = 0.9
epsilon = 10 ** -8

A = [0,2,4,1,2;4,0,0,2,1;3,3,0,5,1;0,1,4,0,0;3,3,0,0,0]

disp("Amount of nodes in this matrix")
n = columns(A)

disp("In degrees")
in_degree = sum(A, 1);

# L1 probability_matrix 
disp("Probability matrix")
probability_matrix = A ./ in_degree

disp("Random suffer vector")
vector = (in_degree / sum(in_degree))'

disp("Google matrix")
google = (alpha * probability_matrix) + (((1-alpha)/n)* ones(n,1))
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Perhaps you could add the [tag:pagerank] tag to you question.

Comment: Didn't know this one exists ^^